# Where is the TexLive 2010 default package directory located in Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: texlive, chemfig

Where is the TexLive 2010 default package directory located in Windows 7 64-bit?

I'm led to believe it should be in C:\texlive\2010\texmf\tex\latex but that appears not to be the case and I cannot find the place where .sty files are held.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaTeX style files for TeXLive on Windows are found in

```
C:\texlive\WXYZ\texmf-dist\tex\latex
```

where WXYZ is the year.

Comment: Incidentally, why can't I find the package chemfig in that directory when my TL manager lists it as being installed?

Comment: @ptrcao: Type `kpsewhich chemfig.sty` at the Command Prompt, and TeX Live will tell you where the file is located. (This of course is a general command: `kpsewhich <filename>`.)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Top suggestion Joe.  Apparently it's in `c:/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/chemfig/chemfig.sty` What is it doing in this folder?  Why does it appear to be treated differently from the rest of the package .stys?

Comment: @ptrcao: Some code (Ti_k_z, for example) is designed to work with plain TeX, LaTeX and ConTeXt. The main body is therefore usually in `generic` rather than `latex`. In some cases, the code gets split up into the LaTeX-specific part and the generic part, but in others (as here) it does not. [P.S. It's 'Joseph', not 'Joe' :-)]

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  [P.S. Sorry, I'm almost accustomed to "Joe" because every Joseph I've ever known has preferred "Joe", but "Joseph" it is in your case. :)]

Comment: @Joseph Wright: P.S. Why do you write it out as "Ti_k_z" rather than just "Tikz", what is the distinction you are making here?

Comment: @ptcao: Drat, the mark up failed. If you look at the Tikz manual, the 'k' is written in italics. (It's to emphasise the 'kein' in the name: TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm'.)

Comment: @ptrcao let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/691/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-ptrcao)

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 7 64-bit computer running TeXLive 2013, the way to get my style (*.sty) files working "natively" is the following

1) put the *.sty file in C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\tex\latex

2) open the TeX Live command line

3) run the command mktexlsr

... as of February 10, 2014

Comment: The default location for private/third party sty files is `$TEXMF/../texmf-local/tex/latex` which translates into `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex` in your specific case.