# TeX Live - change package directory location - Windows

Tags: texlive, windows

In a follow up to this question: [Where is the TexLive 2010 default package directory located in Windows 7 64-bit?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22099/where-is-the-texlive-2010-default-package-directory-located-in-windows-7-64-bit)

If my TeX Live installation is in `C:\texlive\2016` can I change the package directory to anything else other than `C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\tex\latex`?

E.g. can I (somehow) ask TeX Live installed on C: to look for packages on a D: drive?

Reason for question: my TeX Live is installed on a corporate machine where I don't have administrator rights to C: drive hence I cannot add new packages to my distribution.

Comment: In your situation, how does `C:\texlive\2016` get created in the first place? Are you asking about 'updating' your TeX system generally or adding packages manually?

Comment: it's about adding packages manually, system would be installed by the company admin to C:\texlive\2016. If I wanted to add a new package I would have to contact admin each and every time.

Comment: In that case, you may wish to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te: you can install files 'just for you' in your personal tree

Comment: On Windows (and Linux, maybe Mac) TeXlive can be installed as portable, in a user directory. No admin rights needed, as long as you are the user (and if not, on USB). Keep that in mind.

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/296681/latex-filepaths-in-ubuntu

Comment: Packages locations are in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty`

Answer (score 2):

TeXLive will ask you, where to install your system.  You can of course select any different target directory, you have write permissions to.  If you are installing a fresh system from scratch, everything will be fine.

You may also install a complete or incomplete set of packages of an TeX-Directory-Structure (TDS) on `D:` or any other file system.  (I mean: in parallel to any existing TeXLive installation.)  In that case, you have to edit your local settings, to include that TDS-tree into your TeX search path.  (Obviously, you also need to have administration rights, to do that ...)

You have to edit `$TEXMFDIST/web2c/texmf.cnf`, where `$TEXMFDIST` is the root of your TeXLive installation.  In that file, you have to include your second TDS-tree.